# XTDE1150: The regular expression must not be one that matches a zero-length string

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

Im trying to match a regex with a string in xsl. Whichever string is matched I'm adding it to a div.

Here's the messageValue - "102-36.85 - Main section: Handle me"

If the regex is just ^([0-9]), then the first number is matched. But i want to match the whole thing. (102-36.85). What is the problem here? I tested this regex and it's good.

````
                    <xsl:analyze-string  select="$messageValue" regex="^([0-9\-\.]*)?">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <div class="firstSection"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^[0-9]+([.-][0-9]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqeANA/1).

It will match a string that

- `^` - starts with
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `([.-][0-9]+)*` - and then contains 0 or more repetitions of `.` or `-` and then 1+ digits.

Alternatively, you may fix your regex like `^[0-9.-]+`: any 1 or more digits, dots or hyphens at the start of the string.